# Не отображается карта Google на iPhone

Tags: react-native

Добрый день, пишу нативное приложение, использую библиотеку `react-native-maps`, проблема состоит в том что на Android отображается карта Google а на iPhone не корректно, маркеры, местоположение и логотип Google отображаются а сама карта нет. В чем может быть проблема?

Если убрать `provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}` будет отображаться стандартная карта для iPhone. И все будет ок, но мне нужна карта Google.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, Dimensions, Platform, Image } from 'react-native';
import MapView, { PROVIDER_GOOGLE, PROVIDER_DEFAULT } from 'react-native-maps';
import { Input } from 'native-base';

const {width, height} = Dimensions.get('window');

const SCREEN_HEIGHT = height;
const SCREEN_WIDTH = width;
const ASPECT_RATION = width / height;
const LATITUDE_DELTA = 0.0922;
const LONGTITUDE_DELTA = LATITUDE_DELTA * ASPECT_RATION;

const GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY = 'Тут мой ключик)';

class Map extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      initialPosition: {
        latitude: 0,
        longitude: 0,
        latitudeDelta: 0,
        longitudeDelta: 0,
      },
      markerPosition: {
        latitude: 0,
        longitude: 0,
      },
      driverPosition: {
        latitude: 0,
        longitude: 0,
      },
      destination: {
        dist: false,
        latitude: 0,
        longitude: 0
      }
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const options = {
      enableHighAccuracy: true,
      timeout: 10000,
      maximumAge: 0
    }
    this.watchId = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
        let lat = parseFloat(position.coords.latitude);
        let long = parseFloat(position.coords.longitude);
        let initialRegion = {
          latitude: lat,
          longitude: long,
          latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
          longitudeDelta: LONGTITUDE_DELTA,
        }
        let driversRegion = {
          latitude: lat - 0.001,
          longitude: long - 0.0009,
          latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
          longitudeDelta: LONGTITUDE_DELTA,
        }
        this.setState({
          initialPosition: initialRegion,
          markerPosition: initialRegion,
          driverPosition: driversRegion
        })
      },
      (error) => alert(JSON.stringify(error)),options);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(this.watchID);
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <MapView
          provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
          style={styles.map}
          initialRegion={this.state.initialPosition}
          zoomEnabled={true}
          pitchEnabled={true}
          showsUserLocation={true}
          followsUserLocation={true}
          showsCompass={true}
          showsIndoors={true}
          showsBuildings={true}>
          <MapView.Marker
            coordinate={this.state.markerPosition}
            >
            <View style={styles.radius}>
            </View>
          </MapView.Marker>
          {this.state.destination.dist == true ? (
            <MapViewDirections
              origin={this.state.markerPosition}
              destination={this.state.destination}
              apikey={GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY}
              strokeWidth={3}
              strokeColor='rgb(255, 0, 0)'
            />
          ) : []}
        </MapView>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  map: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
  },
  marker: {
  },
  radius: {
  },
  driver: {
  },
  searchText: {
    textAlign: 'center'
  }
});

export default Map;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После долгого мозгового штурма решил поменять ключ Google Maps, убрать все ограничения и зарегистрировать ключ как `Google Maps SDK for IOS`.  Помогло, кто столкнется с такой проблемой, вот решение.